# According to traditional poker rules (excluding Texas holdem), can the ace be used as the low card in a A2345 straight?

Tags: rules

According to traditional poker rules (excluding Texas holdem),can the ace be used as the low card of a straight?

Comment: what do you mean by traditional poker rules? is there a specific type of poker you are referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, A2345 ("wheel") and 10JQKA ("broadway") are both straights in standard poker. In Deuce-to-seven lowball, a wheel is not a straight, but just A5432 high.

Answer (score 1):

With standard rules the ace is the highest card in the deck so it completes straights that run 10 through ace. The ace is also used as the first card in the deck, as a one (like in Blackjack) to complete a five high straight. This does not exclude Texas Hold-em. texas Holdem is played with basic poker hand rankings as is every poker game unless there is mention of it when you settle down to play. even with hi lo variants through high hand ranking is the same. this is true of stud games or draw games. Ace is always the highest card and is always the first card for a straight run through the five, or a wheel. If the game is duece to seven is the low qualifer, then the lowest hand is a seven 23457 an ae would make your hand ace high as far as the low goes. and ace instead of a seven here would make your high hand a 5 high straight and and yur low whatever you can make that is low, like drawing an 8 here would give you an 8 low. texas holdem is rarely played hi-lo.stud draw and omaha is where one finds hi-lo games.when you sit down at a game understand what you are playing. a very popular table is mixed games that tend to get 8-10 varations of poker many of which can be confusing. ask questions at the table. dealers often do not know dince the players are always coming up with new games. especially watch for qualifiers one 5 card draw game they play, might be called archie. has 8 or better for low and pair of 6's for high, if know one qualifiers for high the low scopes the pot. handy stuff to know. and if there i no low the high scopes it. often hand rankings may differ, especially four card games with a draw like bo duggey or spanish poker, be sure to be clear on what it is, very often it is something odd and unexpected like straights beating flushes etc.